# Using Azure OAuth2 token to call Azure DevOps API (user_impersonation scope)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0

I have created and registered an Application in Azure AD, which has multiple API permissions configured, among them Azure DevOps, the only available permission, `user_impersonation`.

I have successfully obtained an OAuth2 token via the full code flow, with requested scope of `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation`.

The access token is JWT, and I have decoded it:

```
{              :tid "bd4570a0-5905-40fb-8ebe-58479aecbc71",
               :rh "0.AS8AoHBFvQVZ-0COvlhHmuy8cb1hUgm2ml5JrS8cjDMq-ZsvAAc.",
               :given_name "R",
               :scp "user_impersonation",
               :email "rl@protonmail.com",
               :aud "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com",
               :sub "h4S-EF9-NYufBaSwlUueuOTJbVnzAtXSeWg7R0_4IwQ",
               :iss "https://sts.windows.net/bd4570a0-5905-40fb-8ebe-58479aecbc71/",
               :name "R L",
               :idp "live.com",
               :exp 1638456612,
               :uti "iHKHjhyHUEGpz4FQ37swAQ",
               :aio "AWQAm/8TAAAA5hRQi967V5w85GNwWSWaJOVjEBs+FTyoWMdjgUQm6qoQoxjNDu1AuAHJuC9cJhWKmu89zXj2z5vNFiytM+wfKuoGrKDDZNAJSXdbWuKau+lTNOyPaugymzVO6q7ODR8W",
               :family_name "L",
               :amr ["pwd" "mfa"],
               :nbf 1638452281,
               :oid "3e18766c-8a5f-49be-9dcf-2c9edf03f6b1",
               :ipaddr "188.230.144.31",
               :appid "095261bd-9ab6-495e-ad2f-1c8c332af99b",
               :unique_name "live.com#rl@protonmail.com",
               :wids ["62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10" "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"],
               :appidacr "1",
               :acr "1",
               :ver "1.0",
               :puid "1003200178C49F6B",
               :iat 1638452281,
               :altsecid "1:live.com:0003BFFD3D75E35F"}
```

So far so good. The important part here is `aud` that is the intended target for token which is `"https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com"` which is Azure DevOps service/resource.

I try to use is as a bearer token when calling Azure DevOps service:
e.g.

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

with header `Authorization` value `Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...`

, I always get back a redirect to `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=app.vssps.visualstudio.com.....`, as if I wasn't authenticated.

Is there some step I am missing here? I have successfully called this endpoint with other types of authentication.

Comment: Did you get the token directly from AAD or from DevOps? Did you follow this tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

Comment: Token is from AAD and I'd like to use it to access DevOps, which because of impersonation I assumed was possible.

Comment: The tutorial you've posted is about using an Azure DevOps App to access Azure DevOps. I've done that and it works fine, but it doesn't support what I need and it has bugs that prevent some uses.

What I want is to use AAD OAuth2 app, which I give access to devops, to then access DevOps.

Comment: @RokL have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No @HadyNourallah I haven't

Comment: @RokL I have managed to do it, I added [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default" })] 
and don't forget to add the devops in your app registration. 

Then I get the token via ITokenAcquisition, and login with new VssAadToken("Bearer", token)